# AngularCLI ng test Cannot find name XY

Tags: angular-cli, angular5

i cannot figure out how to resolve several `Cannot find name '...'` errors when executing `ng test`. It seems like all the components (independent of their location) aren't recognized.

My configuration files look as follows:

`ts.config.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.spec.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

- `Angular CLI: 1.6.6`
- `Node: 8.9.4`

I already tried the settings mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update).

Concrete error messages:

`ERROR in /src/app/shared/service.ts (112,17): Cannot find name 'IUser'.`

Unit tests are so far only the ones which are automatically generated by the `angular-cli`.

Comment: Can you share the full error message(s) you are getting, or at least the parts that are informative? You may want to include a unit test you are having trouble with, too.

Comment: I edited my original post accordingly.

Comment: By the looks of it, you have generated some code, maybe a component, with the CLI. Then, you changed that code to do what you want, but didn't change the associated unit test. Sound right? I would need to see a component's code and unit test to confirm that.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction. As it turned out i had to explicitly export all the interfaces (oddly enough that's not necessary with ng serve)

Comment: If you happen to have your interfaces in the same file as the component, then that would work with ng serve. Since the specs are separate files, an export is needed for the unit test to use them. Glad you figured it out.